# Find Item in multidimensional array by name and return the values which are in the same array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array like this one:

```
array(3) {
    [1]=> array(7) {
        ["label"]=> string(43) "I would like to receive PCN for ETXexpress:"
        ["name"]=> string(48) "ilts_I_would_like_to_receive_PCN_for_ETXexpress:"
        ["type"]=> string(8) "checkbox"
        ["wert"]=> string(2) "on"
        ["html_after"]=> string(0) ""
        ["label_after"]=> string(0) ""
        ["size"]=> string(0) ""
    }
    [2]=> array(7) {
        ["label"]=> string(50) "I would like to recieve PCNs for microETXexpress®"
        ["name"]=> string(55) "ilts_I_would_like_to_recieve_PCNs_for_microETXexpress®"
        ["type"]=> string(8) "checkbox"
        ["wert"]=> NULL
        ["html_after"]=> string(0) ""
        ["label_after"]=> string(0) ""
        ["size"]=> string(0) ""
    }
    [3]=> array(7) {
        ["label"]=> string(38) "I would like to recieve PCNs for ETX®"
        ["name"]=> string(43) "ilts_I_would_like_to_recieve_PCNs_for_ETX®"
        ["type"]=> string(8) "checkbox"
        ["wert"]=> NULL
        ["html_after"]=> string(0) ""
        ["label_after"]=> string(0) ""
        ["size"]=> string(0) ""
    }
}
```

How can I get an array inside it by its name? 
Let's say: From the array that contains: `ilts_I_would_like_to_recieve_PCNs_for_microETXexpress®` the value  `wert` ?

It is important for me, not to point to it by the number in the array.

What is the best way, to do this?

Comment: you can see it is hard to read array element do one thing print your array using `echo '<pre>'; print_r($array);echo '</pre>';` and post the output

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = array( /* your data */ );
$name = "ilts_I_would_like_to_recieve_PCNs_for_microETXexpress®"; // name you are looking for
$result = array();

foreach ( $data as $key => $value ) {
    if ( $value['name'] == $name ) {
        $result = $value;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Denise Check if you have `$result = $value;` because I've corrected it later bacause of misspell.

Comment: @Davood Jafari - I know. `$value` is that inner array and using `$value['name']` I call an element of inner array. What is not clear ?

Comment: My bad. It was not not the spelling error. It way my mistake: i tried to make an array to an array. Now it works fine....Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Test this code, i think this should work .

```
<?PHP
$array = array( /* YOUR DATA */ );

$out = array();

foreach( $array as $a )
{
    if( $a['name'] == 'ilts_I_would_like_to_recieve_PCNs_for_microETXexpress®' )
    {
        $out = $a;
        break;
    }
}

print_r( $out );
?>
```

Comment: `array_search` works (returns key of found element) if you pass as a first argument value that exists in the first level. So if you pass whole array that you are looking for it will returns correct key.
However it will not work in your case when you are looking just for name.
So answering for your question - no, it does not work for a multidimentional array.

Answer (score 0):

why do u not replace array keys (0, 1, 2...) by records name since they're unique. Like this, you can access to your records without search :

```
if (array_key_exists($name, $yourArray))
{
    // your code ..
}
```